# How to enable IIS-level output caching for a MVC route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, iis

I want to enable IIS output caching for ~/sitemap on our website.  However when I look in the IIS Output Cache settings, it asks for the extension, an no where to include the path.

```
<caching>
    <profiles>
        <add extension=".aspx" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
    </profiles>
</caching>
```

The path is www.site.com/sitemap - no extension.

How can I enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the location property of the cache configuration block to refer to a file path and then set the extension within that to be a wild card.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="~/sitemap">
       <system.webServer>
          <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
            <profiles>
              <add extension="*" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
            </profiles>
          </caching>
       </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

The combination of the two should seek to constrain the policy to the outer path `~/sitemap` while overcoming the required extension problem within the `add` rule with the wildcard `*`.

Note: there is also a location attribute within the `add` rule.

This is a different `location` property to what I'm referring to here as it concerns **where to cache** the content (client, server, etc) whereas the recommended outer `location` scopes **what gets cached**.